# How to fetch data dynamically from xml file by tag and nested tag using python?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing

I have an xml file details.xml and the xml file looks something like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="Overpass API 0.7.55.7 8b86ff77">
<meta osm_base="2019-08-02T12:21:02Z"/>

<bounds minlat="19.0983000" minlon="72.8890000" maxlat="19.1184000" maxlon="72.9206000"/>

<node id="245670274" lat="19.1000660" lon="72.8961407" version="5" timestamp="2015-10-27T04:31:16Z" changeset="34895909" uid="3339404" user="Anushka&amp;saroj">
<tag k="AND_a_nosr_p" v="10004762"/>
<tag k="name" v="Kulkarni Wadi"/>
<tag k="place" v="locality"/>
<tag k="source" v="AND"/>
</node>

<node id="245670576" lat="19.1030072" lon="72.8885419" version="4" timestamp="2017-11-22T06:20:01Z" changeset="53992152" uid="1306" user="PlaneMad">
<tag k="source" v="AND"/>
</node>

<node id="619199656" lat="19.1023916" lon="72.9200375" version="3" timestamp="2015-07-03T06:26:42Z" changeset="32379895" uid="2897305" user="Ashok09"/>

<way id="353138857" version="2" timestamp="2015-06-12T10:57:15Z" changeset="31917729" uid="2900596" user="harisha">
<nd ref="3589055782"/>
<nd ref="3589055908"/>
<nd ref="3589055924"/>
<nd ref="3589055914"/>
<nd ref="3589055921"/>
<nd ref="3589055916"/>
<nd ref="3589055922"/>
<nd ref="3589055909"/>
<nd ref="3589055913"/>
<nd ref="3589055904"/>
<nd ref="3589055782"/>
<tag k="building" v="yes"/>
</way>
</osm>
```

I want to fetch all the information inside the 'node' tag and ignore all other things,

for examples in the above xml we have 3 'node' tag and I want all nested(if available else what is available) information from each tag.

The result should look like, if I store those info in a list,

```
ids=['245670576','245670576','619199656'] 
lat=['19.1000660','19.1030072','19.1023916']
lon=['72.8961407','72.8885419','72.9200375']
k=[['AND_a_nosr_p','name','place','source'],['source'],[]]
v=[['10004762','Kulkarni Wadi','locality','AND'],['AND'],[]]
```

How to do it in most efficient way using python ?

Comment: to correlate all subsequent data to each separate node - it's better to store it in a dictionary, don't you think?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I could store it also in dictionary, I need to fetch the data first, How to do it ?

Comment: Your xml is missing a closing tag for `<osm>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extended solution:

```
import pprint
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET().parse(source='input.xml')
nodes_data = {}
for node in tree.findall('./node'):
    k = 'node_' + node.attrib['id']   # custom node key
    nodes_data[k] = node.attrib
    tag_attribs = list(zip(*[tag.attrib.items() for tag in list(node)]))
    if not tag_attribs:
        nodes_data[k].update({'k': [], 'v': []})
    else:
        k_items, v_items = zip(*[tag.attrib.items() for tag in list(node)])
        nodes_data[k].update({'k': [t[1] for t in k_items], 'v': [t[1] for t in v_items]})

pprint.pprint(nodes_data)
```

Actual output:

```
{'node_245670274': {'changeset': '34895909',
                    'id': '245670274',
                    'k': ['AND_a_nosr_p', 'name', 'place', 'source'],
                    'lat': '19.1000660',
                    'lon': '72.8961407',
                    'timestamp': '2015-10-27T04:31:16Z',
                    'uid': '3339404',
                    'user': 'Anushka&saroj',
                    'v': ['10004762', 'Kulkarni Wadi', 'locality', 'AND'],
                    'version': '5'},
 'node_245670576': {'changeset': '53992152',
                    'id': '245670576',
                    'k': ['source'],
                    'lat': '19.1030072',
                    'lon': '72.8885419',
                    'timestamp': '2017-11-22T06:20:01Z',
                    'uid': '1306',
                    'user': 'PlaneMad',
                    'v': ['AND'],
                    'version': '4'},
 'node_619199656': {'changeset': '32379895',
                    'id': '619199656',
                    'k': [],
                    'lat': '19.1023916',
                    'lon': '72.9200375',
                    'timestamp': '2015-07-03T06:26:42Z',
                    'uid': '2897305',
                    'user': 'Ashok09',
                    'v': [],
                    'version': '3'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lxml` for the job.
It has a `findall()` method which you can use.
Then you can iterate over it's `attrib` and parse them into `list`.

Comment: I have tried it but some problem is there, could you write a template ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using

> xml.etree.ElementTree

- Reference:
  https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

I couldn’t get to parsing your copy of xml code. I think this copy has a tag closing problems.
But in general I would use somthing like:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

tree = et.parse('PATH TO XML FILE')
root = tree.getroot()

ids = []
lat = []

for element in root.findall('node'):
    id = element.attrib['id']
    ids.append(id)
    lat = element.attrib['lat']
    ids.append(lat)
```

Mind you that this code was not tested. If there are mistakes in it I apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import lxml.html

xml  = [your xml above]

tree = lxml.html.fromstring(xml)

ids= tree.xpath('//node/@id')
lat = tree.xpath('//node/@lat')
lon = tree.xpath('//node/@lon')
k = tree.xpath('//node/tag/@k')
v = tree.xpath('//node/tag/@v')

print(ids)
print(lat)
print(lon)
print(k)
print(v)
```

Output:

```
['245670274', '245670576', '619199656']
['19.1000660', '19.1030072', '19.1023916']
['72.8961407', '72.8885419', '72.9200375']
['AND_a_nosr_p', 'name', 'place', 'source', 'source']
['10004762', 'Kulkarni Wadi', 'locality', 'AND', 'AND']
```

Comment: the third and fourth list should have 3 elements as well, list of lists